# Property 'browserPrint' does not exist on type 'typeof control'

Tags: angular, browser, printing, leaflet

In my `index.html:

```html
src="/Frontend/node_modules/leaflet.browser.print/src/leaflet.browser.print.js">
```

I get a following error:

```
Error: src/app/Components/map/map.component.ts:76:15 - error TS2339: Property 'browserPrint' does not exist on type 'typeof control'.
    
76     L.control.browserPrint().addTo(map)
```

Please Help

Comment: have you importet the library to your project?

Comment: yes i import : import  'leaflet.browser.print';  but is not working

Comment: I have the same problem.

Comment: I found the solution:                                                                 
 Add in  \node_modules\@types\leaflet\index.d.ts                                                              this script  :  export namespace control {
    function browserPrint(options?: any): Control.BrowserPrint;
  }
 export namespace Control {
    interface BrowserPrint {
      addTo(map: L.Map): any;
    }
  }